# using the browser prompt to download a file

Tags: php, mysql, browser, download, prompt

I have a php/mysql site in which I am trying to download a comma delimited file (CSV). The csv file I create contains comma delimited data (name, address, city, state). I create the csv file ok and place it in the site's /downloads directory. So far so good. I have been looking on line and the code to trigger the browser's download prompt that I see the most often is:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$exportfile = "emailclientaddresses.csv";
$fullpath = "downloads/" . $exportfile;
header("Content-type: text/plain");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($exportfile));
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $fullpath);
```

The $exportfile is the csv file that my code created. It's ok. What this does is:

1. The $fullpath is displayed in the browser download prompt in a very weird format: download_emailclientaddresses.csv
2. When it does download, the current webpage is downloaded or a combination of the csv file and the current web page.

OK, I have tried a lot of things and nothing has worked. So, if anyone can help me I would appreciate it. Thank you.

ed Cohen

Comment: Why did you not except the answer for @Anne as the correct answer, since it is?

Answer (score 38):

The [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) provides a nice example:

```
<?php
$file = 'monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

**EDIT** *(Response to comment, explanation)*

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
```

Do not display in the browser, but transfer the file.

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
```

File is a binary file.
Browsers generally download binary files, unless they can display them.

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
```

Make the download dialog show the proper file name.
Note: You can use any file name.

```
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
```

File should not be cached by the browser.
Cache could cause trouble in case of dynamic content.

```
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
```

Send the correct file size to the browser,
otherwise the browser is unable to estimate the transfer-time.

```
ob_clean();
flush();
```

Make sure the headers are send to the browser before the download starts.

```
readfile($file);
```

Send the file to the browser.

```
exit;
```

Done :)

Comment: Thank you!! This worked like a charm!!! What are all those extra lines? Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you Anne once again. This really helps. It also figures that the answer "was in the book." So to speak. Hmm, maybe I ought to read it once in a while?

Comment: @EdCohen: Please accept the answer (the green checkmark). Let me know if you've got troubles finding that.

Comment: `Content-Length` is not really necessary. I tested sending files without it to Google Chrome, Firefox and Internet Download Manager (IDM) and they could all determine the file size as well as estimated transfer time.