# Downloaded file generated by PHP is getting cut off constistantly at about 47.2kb

Tags: php, sql-server

I am currently working on a utility that pulls files out of an MSSQL database. The body of the files are stored in the database as base64 string which I am decoding with the PHP function `base64_decode()`. To begin the file to download when the page opens I am using the headers:

```
$filename = $file[0][0];
$file_body = base64_decode( $file[0][1] );
$size = $file[0][2];
$type = $file[0][3];

header("Expires: 0"); 
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Length: $size;");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header("Content-Type: $type "); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

echo $file_body;
```

Files download and everything works perfect until the file size is over about 48kb. After that only 48kb of the file is downloaded. I have tested using many files types and still have the same result. I have boosted php memory and post size in php.ini at the suggestion of other posts I have found online, still no luck.

I realize PHP may not be the best way to accomplish this, however, this is what I have available to me.

Any ideas how I can ensure a complete file is always downloaded?

Comment: Can you share the code you are actually creating the file to send it through php?

Comment: @JorgeCampos Updated with the requested code.

Comment: are you running with error_reporting(E_ALL);  ? and verify that the size of the decoded string actually is exactly what you expect.  put: if(strlen($file_body)!==$size){throw new RuntimeException("corrupted data from db! file is supposed to be ".$size." bytes, but is only ".strlen($file_body)." bytes!");}

Comment: @hanshenrik If I print out the decoded string to the screen it matches what I uploaded. If I use the file size I am pulling from the database it never seems to match the string length. Maybe it has been rounded?

Comment: Some quick poking around and found a couple of maybe helpful links:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/11316004/278763 and http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php .  I realize your not reading a file but are streaming contents, but maybe those might help.  Do you need to `flush()` something after the `echo` call?

Comment: @PeterTirrell I tried adding `flush()` and didn't have any luck. It corrupts the file and it can not be opened.

Comment: Still no luck :( Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need  to store length (size) anywhere. You should calculate it on the fly in the following way:

```
$size = strlen($file_body);
...
header("Content-Length: $size;");
```

Comment: Made this change and I am still getting the same results.