# file put contents how to set a path

Tags: php, file-put-contents

I am using file put contents and set a file name but file saved on the directory where the script was written. How to do to set the full path to save to disc or desktop. Something like browse window and save path.

```
$fileName = 'etykieta_' . $package_no . '.' . $xml->label->format;
file_put_contents($fileName, base64_decode($xml->label->base64));
```

And i want to set a file path in a window.

Comment: Show us your code ..!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using the browser prompt to download a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315951/using-the-browser-prompt-to-download-a-file)

Comment: you can use DOCUMENT_ROOT and set path where you want to save this file

e.g $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/yourpath/'; 
file_put_contents($path . $fileName, base64_decode($xml->label->base64));