# using the browser prompt to download a file, within Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a csv file to download, using a technique similar to  [using the browser prompt to download a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315951/using-the-browser-prompt-to-download-a-file)

```
$csv_export = .... csv data...;
header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $csv_filename . "");
echo($csv_export);
exit;
```

The file downloads just fine.  But this is in WordPress, so when I do a php exit; everything stops and the page appears to hang, and the user needs to do a page reload.

Is there any way to do this and/or force a reload so that it does not appear to user to have hung?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you use `exit` in the first place to stop the processing? You could output your content like this too:

```
clearstatcache();
header('Content-Type: '.$type);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
readfile($path);
```

If you really want the processing to stop and didn't send any HTML content you can just use the header redirect:

```
header("Location: http://example.com/myOtherPage.php");
die();
```

If you already send content, you could use JavaScript to reload, but I can't give you an example without more context/code.

Comment: Setting the header to a new page and calling die makes it so no file is saved, and wreaks havoc with Wordpress - get new page at bottom of current.  What did you mean with readfile($path) ?  Saving the content to a file and then re-reading it?

Comment: `readfile` (http://php.net/manual/de/function.readfile.php) will put the file to the output buffer and allow the user to "save" it with the browser promt

Comment: Using readfile as suggested allows the user to save the file (as did my original code using echo)  but the Wordpress page still hangs.  I think the problem is in setting the header, which screws up what Wordpress is doing next.  I'm thinking maybe creating a download link on a new page is the only way to do this.